# Proving that the probability of choosing a letter from words of a given length is $1/n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let us consider the following: suppose I have a word of length $n$ from an ordered alphabet on $n$ letters $\{1, ..., n\}$, i.e., an element $(w_i)$ of $\{n\}^{\{n\}}$.

What is the probability of choosing the first letter $w(1)$ from all possible words, considering that I would choose $w(j)$ over $w(i)$ with probability $1$ if $w(i)>w(j)$, and if I have for some subset $I\subset{n}$ (EDIT: and some $a\in \{n\}$ such that $w^{-1}(a)=I$,)  I am equally likely to choose any element from $I$?

For example, if I wanted to choose a letter from all two-letter words in two-letter alphabet, i.e., $\{1,2\}^{\{1,2\}}=\{(11), (12), (21), (22)\}$, then I will choose the first letter with probability $$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot{1\choose 1}((2-1)^{0}+(2-2)^0)+1\cdot {1 \choose 0}((2-1)^1+(2-2)^1) \right),$$ where I put $(2-2)^0=1$.

In general, I seem to arrive to the formula $$n^{n-1}=\sum_{n>m\ge0,\ n\ge k \ge 1} \frac{1}{n-m}{n-1 \choose m} (n-k)^m.$$ It seems to work for numbers up to $4$.

This seems a bit silly, because obviously any word is equally likely to start with any letter. But I do not quite see how the symmetry helps in the case of this bizarre distribution.

Comment: What's $a$ in $w^{-1}(a)$?

Comment: @joriki I consider $w: \{n\} \to \{n\}, i\mapsto w(i)$

Comment: Indeed. And there's no $a$ in that.

Comment: @joriki Sorry, I used in a sense of a fixed element from $\{n\}$, see the edit above.

Comment: I must confess I have a hard time understanding this problem.

Comment: Did I correctly understand your problem that you ask for a proof that exactly $n$-th part of all possible words starts with a given letter (where $n$ is the number of letters in the alphabet)?

Comment: @user not quite. The question I was asked is about the unconditional probability of choosing the first letter from a word, if, given a word, its first letter is preferable to all others if its value is smaller than the value of all other letters, it is equally preferable to all other letters that have the same value as it does, and will not be chosen if there is even one other letter with the smaller value. But the answer is, indeed, the $n$-th part. I don't personally see why these are equivalent questions.

Comment: @user and if these questions are equivalent, how can the identity I wrote in the question be true? I've tried proving it in ways other than bijective, and it seems impossible.

Comment: I do not understand the exact meaning of the word "preferable". Do you ask about the number of words in which all letters have a larger "value" than that of the first one?

Comment: @user By "preferable" I mean that if I have a word in which all letters have a larger value than the first one, then I would choose the first one with probability 1. As for your question, in the sum above I exclude the words in which at least one letter has a smaller value than the first one, because for such words the probability of choosing the first letter is 0.

Comment: Once more: do you ask about the probability that the first letter in a random word is not larger than any other letter in the word?

Comment: @user No, but I think I can see more clearly what I'm asking: the sum of $1/(the\ number\ of\ letters\ equal\ to\ the\ first\ one)$ over all words in which the first letter is not larger than any other letter in the word, divided by $n^n$

Comment: Does the following formulation correctly reflect your question: "Given a random word a letter with the least value is chosen (in the case there are several such letters one of them is chosen randomly). What is the probability that the chosen letter is the first letter of the word?"

Comment: @user Yes, I believe that's correct.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry, my bad. I would want to sum such values over all possible least values, i.e., what $\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: And what are you looking for? The summation you give seems reasonable, or do you want something simpler?

Comment: It seems quite intuitive that this distribution is symmetrical, since every position is identically and independently distributed, and the selection process has no bias towards certain positions. So you would expect $P[X = i] = 1/n$.

Comment: @TimonKnigge Indeed, it does seem intuitive, all I wanted to know was if my sum works, too, because it seemed a little contrived.

Comment: Specifically, my problem was that I couldn't go from bijective proof to some simpler algebraic relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was clarified in comments the correct statement of the problem is the following:

*Given a random word a letter with the lowest value is chosen (if there are several such letters one of them is chosen randomly). What is the probability that the chosen letter is the first letter of the word?*

In fact the probability in question does not depend on the size of the alphabet $n$ but only on the length of the word $N$. Namely:
$$
p(n,N)=\frac1N.
$$
As already observed in a comment it follows immediately from the symmetry of the problem as any position for the letter with the lowest value in the word is equiprobable, i.e. equal to $\frac1N$.

This can be shown also algebraically. Indeed:
$$
p(n,N)=\frac1{n^N}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{K=1}^N\frac1K\binom{N-1}{K-1}(n-k)^{N-K}\tag1,
$$
where $k$ is the lowest letter value and $K$ is the number of letters with this value in the word. The convention $0^0=1$ is used. Here it is assumed that the first letter in the word has the value $k$ so that the factors $\binom{N-1}{K-1}$ and $(n-k)^{N-K}$ count the number of ways a) to arrange the rest $K-1$ letters with the value $k$ over the rest $N-1$ positions and b) to fill the rest $N-K$ positions with letters having a higher value (from $k+1$ to $n$) , respectively. The factor $\frac1K$ stays for the probability to choose the first letter.

We claim:
$$p(n,N)=\frac1N,
$$
which is due to (1) equivalent to
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{K=1}^N\binom{N}{K}(n-k)^{N-K}={n^N}.\tag2
$$

The validity of the expression (2) is obvious since both sides of the equation count all possible arrangements of the letters in the word of length $N$. (Here the letters with the lowest value are allowed to be arranged in the word quite arbitrarily).

The same result can be obtained by induction. Obviously the claim (2) is valid for $n=1$. Let us show that if it is valid for some $n$ the same is true for $n+1$:
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sum_{K=1}^N\binom{N}{K}(n+1-k)^{N-K}\\
=&\sum_{K=1}^N\binom{N}{K}n^{N-K}
+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\sum_{K=1}^N\binom{N}{K}(n+1-k)^{N-K}\\
=&\sum_{K=1}^N\binom{N}{K}n^{N-K}
+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{K=1}^N\binom{N}{K}(n-k)^{N-K}\\
\stackrel{I.H.}=&\sum_{K=1}^N\binom{N}{K}n^{N-K}+n^N\\
=&(n+1)^N.
\end{align}
$$